# InvalidProjectFileException: "The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' not found" from Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project after upgrading to VS2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, roslyn-code-analysis, dotnet-sdk

We have a tool that loads a `csproj` file with `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project`. It's been working fine for about a year, until we tried running it on a machine with VS2019 installed (and no copy of VS2017). Interestingly enough, it does build just fine with `dotnet build` -- it's only the Build Evaluation that complains about it.

I did see some suggestions to install the 32-bit version of some packages. I didn't try that, but I did try running my executable in 64-bit mode, and it still threw the `InvalidProjectFileException`.

I suspect that I may need to make a small update to point to a different toolset, but since I'm not the author of the code, I'm not entirely sure where to make that change. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

The exception that's thrown:

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.  c:\foo\bar\baz.csproj
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject(String errorSubCategoryResourceName, IElementLocation elementLocation, String resourceName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject[T1](IElementLocation elementLocation, String resourceName, T1 arg0)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, List`1& projects, SdkResult& sdkResult, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImports(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, SdkResult& sdkResult)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate(ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext buildEventContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate(IEvaluatorData`4 data, ProjectRootElement root, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Int32 maxNodeCount, PropertyDictionary`1 environmentProperties, ILoggingService loggingService, IItemFactory`2 itemFactory, IToolsetProvider toolsetProvider, ProjectRootElementCache projectRootElementCache, BuildEventContext buildEventContext, ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, Int32 submissionId, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Reevaluate(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Initialize(IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile)
```

The .csproj in question looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Transports.AspNetCore" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Transports.WebSockets" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Ui.GraphiQL" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Ui.Playground" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Ui.Voyager" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
     <!-- About a dozen references to other .csproj files -->
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="config\FooBar.Config.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here's some information from dotnet.exe:

```
$ dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.503 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.508 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.802 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

$ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.508
 Commit:    9ba8583e91

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  6.3.9600
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win81-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.508\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0
  Commit:  7d57652f33

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.503 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.508 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.802 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

$ type ..\..\..\global.json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.1.508"
  }
}
```

Comment: A co-worker suggested upgrading the `Microsoft.Build` package in the analysis tool, going from `15.9.20` to `16.3.0`. That fixed the problem! (Although that also meant changing the framework version from `4.7` to `4.7.2`...)

Comment: (This is the first time I've answered my own question, so I'm not sure of the etiquette...)

Answer (score 0):

VS 2019. I had the same problem. I was able to fix it via setting the MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable.

```
  Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MSBUILD_EXE_PATH", sdkPath);
```

The trick is that you have to specify the actual MSBuild.exe path (if you have different VSs versions installed, that could be a task to find out the right one).

Here is the code snippet. From the https://github.com/RicoSuter/DNT guys.

```
 private static void SetMsBuildExePath()
        {
            try
            {
                var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("dotnet", "--list-sdks")
                {
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                   UseShellExecute = false
                };
               

                var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
                
                process.WaitForExit(1000);

                var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                var sdkPaths = Regex.Matches(output, "([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+) \\[(.*)\\]")
                    .OfType<Match>()
                    .Select(m => System.IO.Path.Combine(m.Groups[2].Value, m.Groups[1].Value, "MSBuild.dll"));

                var sdkPath = sdkPaths.Last();
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MSBUILD_EXE_PATH", sdkPath);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
               
            }
        }
```

Just use that method before the building process, I assume that will fix the described problem.